# Implementing a BODMAS expression in R without use of * for the 'of' operator

Tags: r

A simple math question requiring the use of BODMAS/PEMDAS, that is, `6/2(1+2) = ?`, has gone viral on Twitter, leading to confusion as to whether the answer is 1 or 9. There are two schools of thought that the 'O' in BODMAS stands for Of instead of the Orders argument. To some, the 'Of' operator means implicit multiplication. Implicit multiplication as in a number multiplied by a bracket seems to take precedence in traditional math over explicit multiplication using the times (X or *) symbol.

How can I implement this implicit multiplication symbol "of" in R? Using the * symbol would convert the 'Of' symbol to an explicit times symbol and might not always lead to the right answer. For example, in R, `6/2*(1+2) = 9` but traditional BODMAS will result in a 1.

Comment: I think you'd always need to have an explicit operator, and you can't define operator precedence in R. See `?Syntax`. Is your last example supposed to be `6/2*(1+2)`?

Comment: @Axeman, yes, I've corrected it. I guess that means, R does not recognize the 'Of' concept?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the "of" concept is. The `2(1+2)` syntax is illegal, since any number could also be a variable, i.e. `a(b+c)` should work the same, but that would be the syntax of a function call.